# Should we have a tag for "ViPER4Android" "ViperFX" or even just "V4A"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see questions on Android Enthusiasts site which relate to Viper4Android, and they are just using the tag [equalizer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equalizer), while others are using the tag [audio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio).  A quick search of that can be found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=ViPER4Android).

I think, it's much better to have a tag [viper4android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viper4android) for that.  Also, the synonyms to the tag would be [viperfx](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viperfx) and [v4a](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v4a).